# TableView is not updating properly after logout and log in

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a ProfileView controller where I display the email of the user that is logged in. When I sign out and sign in again the email is updated but the tableview is not updated when new info. Even if it is done the reloading is just appending duplicating rows to the view. Below is my code. Can someone check what I may be doing wrong

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import SDWebImage
import FirebaseDatabase
final class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var data = [ProfileViewModel]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email! else {
          return
        }
        
        tableView.register(ProfileTableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell.identifier)
        data.append(ProfileViewModel(viewModelType: .info,
                                    title: "Email: \(email ??  "No Email")",
                                    handler: nil))
      
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableHeaderView = createTableHeader()
       
       
       
    }
   

    func createTableHeader() -> UIView? {
        guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: email)
        let filename = safeEmail + "_profile_picture.png"
        let path = "images/"+filename

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                        y: 0,
                                        width: self.view.width,
                                        height: 300))

        headerView.backgroundColor = .link

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (headerView.width-150) / 2,
                                                  y: 75,
                                                  width: 150,
                                                  height: 150))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.backgroundColor = .white
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.width/2
        headerView.addSubview(imageView)

        StorageManager.shared.downloadURL(for: path, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to get download url: \(error)")
            }
        })

        return headerView
    }

}

extension ProfileViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let viewModel = data[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell.identifier,
                                                 for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
        cell.setUp(with: viewModel)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        data[indexPath.row].handler?()
    }
}

class ProfileTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "ProfileTableViewCell"

    public func setUp(with viewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
        self.textLabel?.text = viewModel.title
        switch viewModel.viewModelType {
        case .info:
            textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            selectionStyle = .none
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not empty data array before appending new data to it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: You use `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email")` and `Auth.auth().currentUser?.email` which one is truth ?

Comment: I am not using UserDefaults.standard for the tableview because it had some other issues, nevertheless, I had similar issue there.You say I do not empty the data array before appending. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to empty data array before appending new object into that array.
just write
`data.removeAll()` before
`data.append(ProfileViewModel(viewModelType: .info, title: "Email: \(email ??  "No Email")", handler: nil))`.

I think this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I am happy to help